# redirect to maintenance page issue

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My maintenance page to my site has a rather odd glitch, the page is redirecting but something in the htaccess code is blocking the css and  javascript files. Please take a look at my code there's something in it that's not quite right, because5 when I remove the redirect the css loads as normal.

```
#
# Redirection to the Maintenance Page
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^25\.210\.157\.0
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)
RewriteRule .* /maintenance.html [R=307,L]
#
#
```

Found the answer, but is there any easier way, instead of selecting all type of file to an all encompassing command?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|ico|woff|eot|svg|ttf)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^25\.210\.157\.0
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance\.html$ [NC]
# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* /maintenance.html [R=307,L]
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava that does the same job, but cleaner.